Where do I find the Flutter web environment declarations in Chrome?
If I run a Flutter web application defining a variable such as --dart-define=flavor="staging", is there a way to find it in Chrome Developer Tools? I have tried to look it inside the main.dart.js file but I couldn't find it.
I need to check if Azure is setting this variable properly, because I'm uploading my Flutter web app using a task, but this variable looks like doesn't get defined properly, since the uploaded version doesn't have the things that flavor staging should have.
  - task: FlutterBuild@0
    inputs:
      target: "web"
      projectDirectory: "."
      verboseMode: true
      dartDefine: 'flavor="$(flavour)"'
      extraArgs: "--release"
    displayName: "Web Build"



Yes, actually you can do it. When you are fetching the flavor from the environment, you usually get the flavor by
String.fromEnvironment(''),
now you can store that value in the Shared Preferences, and it will be visible under Browser-> application-> local storage. by this you can actually fetch the flavor of the web app that you are running since shared preferences uses browser's local storage api in the application.

